# I need to retrieve from this array point where the X is the biggest number

Tags: c#, .net

I have points struct array:

```
Point[] arr  = samples.pointsArray;
```

I need to retrieve from this array point where the X is the biggest number.

```
  Point maxX= (some logic);
```

Any idea how I can implement this?

Comment: "X is the smallest number." What is X?

Comment: X is th biggest number. i did mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `OrderBy` and `First` LINQ operators:

`Point minX = arr.OrderBy(p => p.X).First();`

`Point maxX = arr.OrderByDescending(p => p.X).First();`
or
`Point maxX = arr.OrderBy(p => p.X).Last();`

Alternative solution (without using `OrderBy`):
[How to get the Point with minimal X from an array of Points without using OrderBy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574330/how-to-get-the-point-with-minimal-x-from-an-array-of-points-without-using-orderb?rq=1)

Comment: Any reason you changed the answer from .Min to OrderBy?

Comment: @Ganesh Because I noticed the OP wanted the **Point** with the lowest X, not the lowest X.

Answer (score 1):

Without needing to reorder the array (!?!) as suggested by @Rotem, you can simply do:

```
int maxX = arr.Max(p => p.X);
Point maxXPt = arr.First(p => p.X == maxX);
```

Note this is done in O(n) whereas the `OrderBy` method is O(n log n).